# Render JSON from GET request

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, get

I am wanting to render the response after I have done a GET request on my API to the react-native application. I am unsure how to go about this. As you can see in my code, I have tried multiple things such as `JSON.stringify` which I thought may parse my JSON correctly.

```
var data;

var footballTeasersApp = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8088/teasers/1", {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData.question));
          return ( 
              data = responseData.question
          )
        })
        .done();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonGET} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)} //I want to render the response here</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>POST</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    },

});
```

The JSON that is returned is the following:

```
{
  "question": "Which three Spaniards played in the 2007 Champions League Final?",
  "answer": "Pepe Reina, Alvaro Arbeloa, Xabi Alonso",
  "id": 1
}
```

**Please note:** I do not wish to have to click a button to render the response, I want the app to do a get request on load and render the response.

Comment: have you tried JSON.parse()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I have tried this yes, but I am not sure that the `componentDidMount()` function is working. What I am actually wanting to do is, do a GET request on the API, and then render the result, before anything else happens.

Comment: See my answer below. Technically it should work. :) Although I could be wrong or misunderstanding your question.

Comment: What exactly is in that json?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, it does log to the console, however it does not render.

Comment: Ok from I can see, you are accessing {data}. Try accessing its properties using dot notation. Because at the moment you are trying to output whole object. {data.question} where question goes etc

Comment: as I thought `data` is undefined, I believe this is because nothing is triggering the `fetch()`. Could this be because my `componentDidMount` is incorrect? Just to confirm, I want it to do the `GET` request before anything is rendered to the app, and then when this `GET` request is complete, I want to render the result.

Comment: Hmm I don't know much about ReactJS to be honest. Are you calling footballTeaserApp somewhere? You might only need to call the function somewhere within your code. Try removing  var footballTeasersApp =  and leaving the rest. Then I assume the function will run when parser comes accross it

Comment: or simply create self invoking function

Comment: It needs to be like this, because `footballTeaserApp` is in the `AppRegistry`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data;

var footballTeasersApp = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:8088/teasers/1", {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(responseData.question));
          return ( 
              data = JSON.parse(responseData.question)
          )
        })
        .done();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{data.question}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonGET} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>{data.answer} //I want to render the response here</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text>POST</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    },

});
```

Not 100% but this might work.

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.
>
> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

After parsing the object, you can access its properties using dot notation such as {data.name}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure you've completely understood, please see my edits. Thanks!

Comment: I also think that because it is a JSON object it needs `stringify`-ing.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally...got this to work, required a little bit of refactoring but here we go:

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:8088/teasers/1';

export default class footballTeasersApp extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {question: '?'}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData().done()
    }
    async fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(URL)
      const json = await response.json()
      const question = json.question
      this.setState({question})
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {this.state.question}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
```